# Optimal relationship of a cone

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

1. Consider right circular cone-shaped paper cups available when getting a drink from a water cooler. To save resources one seeks to **maximize** the volume of liquid a cup holds when each has the same surface area so the same amount of paper is used for each cup. What is the **optimal** relationship between the base radius r and the height h of the optimal cone?

---

I'm confused on how to even approach this. We are currently doing Kuhn-Tucker conditions and Lagrange multiplier rules.

Comment: My gut tells me you can use implicit differentiation here and only use Calculus I tooks.

Comment: Yeah using calc this would be more manageable, but this project is supposed to be based on the material we used in class. Which are the subjects I said in the question. Thanks tho @GFauxPas